# Getting logs from remote windows systems in Elastic Search ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to Elasticsearch and logstash. I wanted to know if there's a way to get windows event logs of remote systems which login to my server(which has logstash) where the windows systems don't have any logpusher software on them.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Any chance to install [Winlogbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/index.html) on your remote systems to gather logs and forward them to a central Logstash?

Comment: Nope, I am sorry that isn't an option in my case.

Comment: Well somehow you need to get those logs out of your remote systems, Logstash alone will not be able to fetch them just like that.

Comment: I'm assuming that if you can't install Winlogbeat, it means you can't install anything on the remote machine. If you can't install anything on remote machine I don't think you will be able to achieve this. If you think about it, it would be a severe security issue.

Comment: Yeah..my thoughts exactly, just wanted to check. Thanks